# For Google Apps Script: suggested deployment route to enable Android smart phone capability?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a nifty Google Apps Script app that I have developed. I would now like to port it to work on Android smart phones. Is there any suggested migration route to do this?

I know that Google Apps Script is already based on Google Web Toolkit, does that mean that I can use the same GUI widgets? For example the a vertical panel?

Thank You,
Commet

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean installable Android Apps. If so, I have not come across yet anything which can port you GAS code to Android Apps.
If you mean a web application, You can access you published apps script application on your android phone via service URL using your android browser.

Comment: Not all GWT widgets are "touch friendly". I had some issues myself, but it mostly works...

Answer (score 0):

As Waqar mentioned, the best way is to have your GAS UI open up in the browser. And yes, Henrique is also right - not all UI elements are touch friendly.

Please also see an issue open for this - http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1092